# TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined at Line 100

Tags: google-app-engine, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

When executing function, it invoques the other function ( registrarOcupacion() invoques to procesarHojaOcup(hojaOrigen))then, when processing the macro I get an error on line 100:

Line 100: matriz.push(aux.concat(semana,fechas[semana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F6pt.png),fechas[semana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Rram.png),fechas[semana][6],datos[f][c] * 8,'','Ocupación'))

Message Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined (line 100, file"macroPlaneacion")Close

Before it works pretty well, but now I try to scope data source to other bigger sheet and doesn't work at concat fechas[semana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F6pt.png),fechas[semana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Rram.png),fechas[semana][6]

Logger registery:

10 jun. 2020 13:55:44   Información 27.0
10 jun. 2020 13:55:45   Información null
10 jun. 2020 13:55:45   Error   TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined
    at procesarHojaOcup(macroPlaneacion:101:55)
    at registrarOcupacion(macroPlaneacion:29:7)

My maternal language is Spanish, this is why sometimes you will find comments in spanish

**SOURCE CODE**

```
function registrarOcupacion(){
  let archivoDestino = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let hojaDestino = archivoDestino.getSheetByName('BD');
  var hojaOrigen = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  let archivoOrigen = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/187Mvtj_ExSQ9nil_NbwNmSTcjZ_X1i6GfXcOMMMnn7Y/edit#gid=858356230');

  //crear fechas
  fechas = archivoDestino.getSheetByName('Calendario').getDataRange().getValues()
  personas = archivoDestino.getSheetByName('Personas').getDataRange().getValues()

  let hojasArchivoOrigen = archivoOrigen.getSheets()
  for(let h of hojasArchivoOrigen){
    let nombre = h.getName()
    if(nombre.substr(0,1) != '_'){
      let hojaOrigen = h
      procesarHojaOcup(hojaOrigen)
    }
  }

  let rangoDestino = hojaDestino.getRange(2, 1, matriz.length, matriz[0].length)
  rangoDestino.setValues(matriz)
  Browser.msgBox('Fin del proceso')
}


function procesarHojaOcup(hojaOrigen) {

  let datos = hojaOrigen.getDataRange().getValues()
  for(let f = 3, l = datos.length; f < l; f++){
    if(datos[f][0] != '' && datos[f][0] != 'Totales'){
      let persona = personas.filter(p => p[0] == datos[f][0])
      let aux = [
        hojaOrigen.getName()
      ]
      aux = aux.concat(persona[0])
      aux = aux.concat(
        datos[f][1],
        datos[f][2],
        datos[f][3]
      )
      for(let c = 21; c <= 57; c++){
        if(datos[f][c] !=''){
          let semana = datos[2][c]
          matriz.push(aux.concat(semana,fechas[semana][4],fechas[semana][5],fechas[semana][6],datos[f][c] * 8,'','Ocupación'))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('', hojaOrigen.getName())
}
```

Google Sheet Data:

Calendar: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvrsQ.png)

People is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4kg8.png)

And the data extracted:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMpek.png)

Expected results:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F6pt.png)

The macro do as well as expected the job, but I don't know what I did

Resolvin that, in hours bussy I need this.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet giving you this error?

Comment: And also include the definition of `matriz`?

Comment: Yes, I'll update. And Matriz is void

Comment: Thank you, for debugging  it would be more helpful if you could provide an actual spreadsheet (a copy that does not contain personal data, but has the same structure, amount of rows/columns etc.) rather than screenshots.

Comment: A spreadsheet with share link or only a screenshot?

Comment: Link of data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1naHm-28Hahv-P0_-q8Aobz8RDQkcky8VrWQY5cWPbY8/edit?usp=sharing.  Link of Macro: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xLDjqwoqhg9BKQ6Rib2eugAc0dk8af-OEPFjtMy8AvI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: An actual link so I could test your code on the speradsheet. Because your error seems related to the specific structure of the data in your sheets.

Comment: I did it, there is not sensible data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your problem originates from you query your data

- `function procesarHojaOcup(hojaOrigen)` retrieves the data range of each sheet that is passed to the funciton
- `for(let f = 3, l = datos.length; f < l; f++)` loops through all data rows from 4 to the last one
- `for(let c = 21; c <= 57; c++)` loops through all columns from 22 to 58
- Now careful! `if(datos[f][c] !=''){` tests either the content of `datos[f][c]` is not blank, but it does not test if `datos[f][c]` exists!
- If `datos[f][c]` does not exist  - `semana` will be undefined and consequently `fechas[semana][4]` and so on do not exist and will throw you an error

### What to do?

- Replace `if(datos[f][c] !=''){` by `if(datos[f][c]){` in order to resolce your recent error
- Double-check either your row and column values are as intended (do you really have 58 columns)?
- Doublechek either your really want to run the function `procesarHojaOcup()` on all sheets of your spreadsheet
- Implement plenty of `Logger.log` statements to help troubleshooting
- It is particulary useful to log `f`, `c`, `semana` and `fechas` inside your loops and `if` statements

Comment: Thanks a lot, "Replace if(datos[f][c] !=''){ by if(datos[f][c]){ in order to resolve your recent error" was the solution

Comment: I have a new problem, by resolve that problem, this date is empty datos[f][c] * 8,

Comment: So probably there is not data in `datos[f][c]` of the sheet you are querying? Log the sheetname that gives you the error and keep in mind that arrays start with index 0.

Comment: In logger that bring me correct information, but in sheet bring me a date

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understood your problem. Is it about if a cell exists but is empty? Then you can use a twofold `if` statement: `if(datos[f][c] && datos[f][c] !=''){ `

Comment: I need to bring an hours in, for example "Analtica Cadena Abastecimiento" and multiply for 8 (number of hours of work for week) and that bring me a date instead a numebr

Comment: It works, your comment resolve my problem and cell format was a date. I have a problem with range of data now